# User role based routes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I'm using react for my frontend

I'm having a login, forgot password in my routing

Based on user type I need to include a few sets of routes

**Ex**

- User Type

  ```
  Student:
      Dashboard, Profile, View Attendance 
  Teacher :
      Dashboard, Profile, add Attendance, Student Profile
  ```

After login then only I know user type.

If I load all the routes while rendering the app component, unwanted routes are loaded.

So the student can use the Teacher component. This might leads to problems.

How to rid of this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use [react-authorization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-authorization) to wrap the component in the route and allow only users in specific roles to view it. You can also define an error component which would be displayed to an unauthorized user. Here's an example (in TypeScript):

```
const AdministrationRoute: React.FC<AdministrationRouteProps> = props => {
    const accessDeniedError = <div className="ml-3 mr-3"><Alert
        color="danger">Access denied!</Alert></div>;
    return <IfGranted expected="ROLE_ADMIN" actual={props.user.roles} unauthorized={accessDeniedError}>
        <Users/>
    </IfGranted>;
};
```

And then use the component in a route as usual:

```
<Route path={Routes.administration.path} component={AdministrationRoute}/>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I am the author of the react-authorization library.